# Which module in django-fiber loads the scripts in the <head> tag?

Tags: django

I'm using django-fiber version 0.10, and the github sample project 'django-fiber-example'.  I added django_debug_toolbar to INSTALLED_APPS, which didn't initially work, until I added a newer version of jquery than default version 1.5.2 automatically loaded into the  section by django-fiber.

When you examine the  section of the html page generated by django-fiber, there are 18 JavaScript and 3 CSS files loaded.  Are these loaded by django-fiber or by the django-fiber-example project?  Which module or template causes these files to be loaded?

Comment: I just found the location where these files are loaded:  templates/fiber/header.html

Comment: The code that loads the header template is in the file fiber/middleware.py, the method AdminPageMiddleware.get_header_html(self, request).  This method has the template "fiber/header.html" hard-coded.